# Cannot remote debug WSL2 C/C++ program with Visual Studio 2022 Cross-Platform settings

Tags: visual-studio, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-2022, remote-debugging, wsl-2

Please go through following MSDN question I posted: [MSDN - Cannot remote debug WSL2 C/C++ program with Visual Studio 2022 Cross-Platform settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1378001/cannot-remote-debug-wsl2-c-c-program-with-visual-s)

Environment (All x64) - Windows 11 (22621.2361), Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.7.4 , Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL2

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

When we chose in built toolset provided by Visual Studio

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Remote File Explorer is always empty even connection is verified and established when we do remote GCC connection mode as highlighted.

[image]

[image]

---

### But I could easily access linux file system via **VSCODE**
[image]

### Also, through PowerShell I could SSH into the WSL2 linux system using credentials simply.
[image]
[image]

***Is this a well-known issue or is it a problem of SSH configuration of WSL2 or Windows?***

Comment: Please post everything here, as text as much as you can, in order to make the question self sufficient; the day the msdn post is deleted or link changed, the question here will be worthless.

Comment: Ok I will let me edit ...

Comment: @Soleil why did you vote to close? is this how Stack overflow works? if the question is too textual it goanna be bloated and borring right ?

Comment: Before your edit your question was not fit for SO, so I voted to close. SO is not for entertainment, but programming. Just text is not boring. If another programmer can't understand or reproduce your problem, you won't have any help. Sometimes we just copy your code to test it, so it's always better to have everything as text. Now it's better, but I still don't undertand your problem and there are no question, so, very likely you won't have any answer, until you improve your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask